# How to get all heights of rows in p-dataTable (PrimeNG)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

My question is simple, but not easy to do. I need height of all **rows** in my p-dataTable -> for example in array. It is possible to get all heights?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working for me!

```
 ::ng-deep .your-table .ui-datatable-scrollable-view .ui-datatable-scrollable-body {
        min-height: 27vh;
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I get the result using this:

```
let rowHeights = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-datatable-tablewrapper");
let rowHeightsFiltered = rowHeights[0].children[0].children[1].children;
```

Then I put values to the array:

```
let eacheRowHeight = new Array;
for (let i = 0; i < rowHeightsFiltered.length; i++) {
  eacheRowHeight.push(rowHeightsFiltered[i].clientHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
<tr pInitEditableRow [pEditableRow]="rowData" [pContextMenuRow]="rowData" style="height: 25px;">

<td style="width:130px;text-align:left" ><span icon="pi-folder"></span> {{rowData.COLUMN_NAME}}</td>

</tr>
</ng-template>
```

This Just Worked for me by adding the style property